# How to surround JTable with JScrollPane through windowbuilder?

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, swing, eclipse-plugin

In Eclipse Jigloo plugin you can right click on JTable and choose "surrond with JScrollPane".

But in windowbuilder pro plugin I can't find a way to make JTable with JScrollPane

Comment: Add JScrollPane and put JTable inside?

Comment: well, I see that JTable is inside of JScrollPane, but I can't see actual JTable // т.е. там таблицу не видно вообще, она вставляется как viewport и всё :) как-то странно...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a scroll pane to your UI. Then drag and drop the table onto the scroll pane. During the drag over scroll pane window builder will highlight its areas - make sure you drop onto the central one.

Comment: Спасибо, я вставляю таблицу в тот центральный квадрат, но тогда ее просто становится не видно.. Видно только JScrollPane

Comment: It works! Thank you. So you need first create JTable model and after that drag it to scroll pane

Comment: Just drop it in there. The table has no dimensions unless it has a model. The model usually set dynamically in your application.
Sorry for not responding in Russian - most users here wouldn't understand it :)

Comment: That works, but what do you do when you can't drag and drop into a JScrollPane? For example, when a JScrollPane is only selectable in the components window?

Comment: Then I would suggest doing it the simplest possible way - right one line of code: scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

Answer (score 4):

Alteratively the following also works nicely;

1. Add a JTable
2. Right click on the JTable in the tree view
3. Select: Surround With > JScrollPane

Comment: This works in Jigloo, but in windowbuilder pro v8 I can't find any "Surround With" menu..

Comment: the validated solution didn't work for me, this one has. I use the Spring packaging of Eclipse, version 2.9.2, with WindowBuilder 1.5.0

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use NetBeans to do some of your Swing layout.

I've had limited experience with WindowBuilder, but I use NetBeans for designing prototypes and find it much easier for creating UIs. The resulting code generated from NetBeans will also be viewable using WindowBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

I am using WindowBuilder 1.7.0 and Swing designer 1.7.0 in Eclipse in Mac. At first I was finding similar menu like Jigloo which I did not find. My Jigloo always crash in Mac and show license message, so I discarded it :)
Later with some playing, I found how to do it in WindowBuilder, specially if you have already designed the JTable/JTextArea/JTree and do not want to delete it. After that you need to put them scrollable. 
You can use the tree view on the left. Normally you cannot drag a component into the scroll view. However add the scroll view in the frame. Set proper layout to the component where you want to put the scroll view. Usually its BorderLayout, may in a JPanel. Drag the JScrollView into target area. Use the tree view for all these actions. Then finally drag the JTree/JTable into the JScrollPane in the frame design view. To my experience this works better. Play with the Layouting of the parent components.

[image]